# How to solve a file path as a failed dependency when installing a RPM?

Tags: cron, rpm, dependencies

I have a RHEL 6 server without any internet access that is missing a cron installation.

I am trying to install crontabs like this but I get this error:

```
[root@netsrvr01 cron.d]# rpm -ivh /Downloads/crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm
warning: /Downloads/crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        /etc/cron.d is needed by crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch
[root@netsrvr01 cron.d]# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendline'
```

What does it mean `/etc/cron.d is needed`? I do have those directories and I am logged in as root.  Unfortunately, I don't have a similar machine where I can use yum downloader for either.

**RPM contents:**

```
[root@netsrvr01 Downloads]# rpm -qpl /Downloads/crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm
warning: /Downloads/crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/crontab
/usr/bin/run-parts
/usr/share/man/man4/crontabs.4.gz
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of this RPM? `rpm -qpl /Downloads/crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm`.

Comment: @slm rpm contents have been added. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Idea #1 - directory already exists

Try running the command `rpm -Uvh --test /Downloads/crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm` first to see if it reports anything out of the ordinary. If not then do an upgrade of this package instead of an install.

I believe it's complaining because this directory already exists, but it's unclear by whom. On my CentOS 6 boxes this directory shows as being owned by the package `cronie`.

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/cron.d
cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64
```

When I look at the contents of the `crontabs` package I see the following content:

```
$ repoquery -l crontabs
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/crontab
/usr/bin/run-parts
/usr/share/man/man4/crontabs.4.gz
```

Notice there is no `/etc/cron.d`. If you run the following command however you'll see that `crontabs` requires the following resources:

```
$ rpm -qp --requires crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch.rpm 
/bin/bash  
/etc/cron.d  
config(crontabs) = 1.10-33.el6
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

#### Idea #2 - verify `cronie` package

So this is where the requirement is coming from. I would run the following command to confirm that the package `cronie` is correctly installed:

```
$ rpm -V cronie --verbose
.........    /etc/cron.d
.........    /etc/cron.d/0hourly
.........  c /etc/cron.deny
.........  c /etc/pam.d/crond
.........    /etc/rc.d/init.d/crond
.........  c /etc/sysconfig/crond
.........    /usr/bin/crontab
.........    /usr/sbin/crond
.........    /usr/share/doc/cronie-1.4.4
.........  d /usr/share/doc/cronie-1.4.4/AUTHORS
.........  d /usr/share/doc/cronie-1.4.4/COPYING
.........  d /usr/share/doc/cronie-1.4.4/ChangeLog
.........  d /usr/share/doc/cronie-1.4.4/INSTALL
.........  d /usr/share/doc/cronie-1.4.4/README
.........  d /usr/share/man/man1/crontab.1.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man5/crontab.5.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man8/cron.8.gz
.........  d /usr/share/man/man8/crond.8.gz
.........    /var/spool/cron
```

Comment: @Quinma - see additions to my answer.

Comment: @Quinma - If you want you can get the installation disk and just manually `scp` the crontabs file to your remote server.

Comment: @Quinma - what was the actual issue?

Comment: idea #2 is the issue, cronie is not installed correctly and I need to use the idea from #1 in order to get that installed correctly. This server is a mess and your shared knowledge on package resources will help me get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the installation disc, you may want to try to do a repair if the disc provides that feature. Or, you may try to install all of the cron packages from the installation disc.

Comment: That is a good answer, unfortunately in my case the server is remote